# Is it possible to build a hybrid wrapper for IOS and Android with push notification functionality

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I want to build and App for both IOS and Android. The App will act as a wrapper for a website but will include some native behaviours such as push notifications. Does anyone have any advise on how to build a wrapper for both ios and android with this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone if in a similar situation: The Website that is being wrapped if being built with Rails using Turbolinks so I'm going to build two wrappers one with turbolinks-ios and the other with turbolinks-android. 
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks